# Networking and Timing issue

Tags: unity, networking, unity-networking, socket

I have been trying to use the low-level API for UNET and the focus of this problem is this: `NetworkEventType recData = NetworkTransport.Receive(out recHostId, out connectionId, out channelId, recBuffer, bufferSize, out dataSize, out error);`
This line is supposed to take in information from many different clients and sits within Update() function. I haven't actually started coding anything in yet... But the point is, if the clients are all transmitting data to the server at a rate equivalent to Update() then this line of code will not be able to (I think?) receive all of them at once (10+ clients vs 1 server). So is there a way to not lose any of the incoming data and process them accordingly?

Comment: Have you considered a while loop to keep checking until there are no more events to process? (Up to some maximum to avoid live-locking it)

Comment: oh no actually I didn't think of that, nice one!